# Is this valid implementation of ServiceLocator pattern in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, service-locator

I have an existential doubt. I saw an implementation of ServiceLocator pattern in C++ in some blog ([Service Locator](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/service-locator.html)). So, I'm trying to extend the same implementation on Java SE (without any other auxiliar framework). See below the code.

My question: Is that a valid implementation for the ServiceLocator pattern in java?. If not is the case, what could be the most simple (example) implementation for this pattern in java?

```
/**
 * Where MyService1 and MyService2 are interfaces.
 */
public final class MyServiceLocator {

private static MyService1 service1;

private static MyService2 service2;

private MyServiceLocator() {
    // No op
}

public static MyService1 getMyService1() {
    if (service1 == null) {
        throw new NullMyService1Exception();
    }
    return service1;
}

public static MyService2 getMyService2() {
    if (service2 == null) {
        throw new NullMyService2Exception();
    }
    return service2;
}

public static void provideService1(MyService1 service1) {
    // Initialize Service1
    ...
    MyServiceLocator.service1 = service1;
}

public static void provideService2(MyService2 service2) {
    // Initialize Service2
    ...
    MyServiceLocator .service2 = service2;
}
```

}

Comment: You are aware of the [java.util.ServiceLoader class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html), right?  If you’re trying to do this for academic reasons, then the point of a service locator is to either have a well-defined algorithm for discovering a particular type of service, or to have a public registry of services, with which a library can register itself.  Your code appears to do neither.

Comment: Existential doubt? Sounds pretty serious...

Comment: Hi @shmosel, only is a way to say that I have many doubts about it, no one will die for that. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @Ariel , one comment: you should never have classes named SomethingManager, SomethingService etc. https://blog.codinghorror.com/i-shall-call-it-somethingmanager/

Comment: Of course, this is not the production code @SupunWijerathne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I see no problem with your implementation according to Service-Locator pattern, other than absence of caching strategy & using single access methods rather than having unique getters/setters for each service as explained in some sources. [This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/service_locator_pattern.htm) might be a more clear example.

But it looks like a [terrible](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) pattern. What is the need of that? As your [source](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/service-locator.html) suggests, it's a way to contain a set of worker classes (which are implementing a common interface), and expose to clients without using [Singletons](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton).

I don't see this as a good solution at all in terms of extend-ability. What will happens when you have to add to more services?? You have to

- add more and more methods (in your way)
- reproduce all the if-else ladders used to locate any service (as explained in the source I put)

which looks quite terrible.

If you have a set of services which are exposing same functionality to clients(i.e. implementing same interface), the best ways to expose them preserving the common behavior is either of

- [Strategy](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) with [Dependency-Injection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections) or
- [Command](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command)

patterns.